# I'm trying read 3 or more column from CSV file, it giving me an index error. anyone have an idea

Tags: csv, groovy, soapui

```
//Create a new filereader object, using the context variable so it can be used between test components
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('C:/data.csv'))
//Read in the first line of the data file
//this is the code fro the testcase 

firstLine = context.fileReader.readLine()
//Split the first line into a string array and assign the array elements to various test case properties
String[] propData = firstLine.split(",")
testCase.setPropertyValue("data1",propData[0])
testCase.setPropertyValue("data2",propData[1])
testCase.setPropertyValue("data3",propData[2])

//Rename request test steps for readability in the log; append the element name to the test step names
testCase.getTestStepAt(0).setName("data1-" + propData[0])
testCase.getTestStepAt(1).setName("data2-" + propData[1])
testCase.getTestStepAt(2).setName("data3-" + propData[2])

//this is the Code that reads from CSV file
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('C:/data.csv'))
/*Read in the next line of the file
  We can use the same fileReader created in the Setup script because it
  was assigned to the context variable.*/
nextLine = context.fileReader.readLine()
/*If the end of the file hasn't been reached (nextLine does NOT equal null)
  split the line and assign new property values, rename test request steps,
  and go back to the first test request step*/
if(nextLine != null){
    String[] propData = nextLine.split(",")
    curTC = testRunner.testCase
    curTC.setPropertyValue("data1",propData[0])
    curTC.setPropertyValue("data2",propData[1])
    curTC.setPropertyValue("data3",propData[2])

    curTC.getTestStepAt(0).setName("data1-" + propData[0])
    curTC.getTestStepAt(1).setName("data2-" + propData[1])
    curTC.getTestStepAt(2).setName("data3-" + propData[2])

    testRunner.gotoStep(0)
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting. Does anyone have any idea? I'm trying to read more than 3 columns from the CSV file, please help.

```
TestCase failed [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2], time taken = 0
```

Here is CSV file data:

```
Hydrogen,1,H,1.00797,20.4
Carbon,6,C,12.0115,5100
Oxygen,8,O,15.9994,90.2
Gold,79,Gd,196.967,3239
Uranium,92,U,238.03,4091
```

Comment: Without seeing the data in "data.csv", I'd have to guess there's a line in there that doesn't have 2 commas in it.  Maybe the last line of the file, if your last line of real data has a carriage return after?

Comment: Can you use a real [CSV parser](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv)?

Comment: Hydrogen,1,H,1.00797,20.4
Carbon,6,C,12.0115,5100
Oxygen,8,O,15.9994,90.2
Gold,79,Gd,196.967,3239
Uranium,92,U,238.03,4091 
here is the data from the CSV opened in Text file format

Comment: Please add the csv content to your question, not a comment.

Comment: The error message says it all: one of your arrays has only 2 elements. The line number in the stack trace should tell you *where* the exception is thrown.

Comment: It hardly matters for the question, but Gold's symbol is Au, not Gd.

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenCSV instead for parsing CSV files with Java or Groovy. You can add the jar to the Groovy classpath (and dynamically resolve their dependencies) by using Grapes like this:

`@Grab(group='com.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='3.3')`

Comment: Im New to SoapUI, i have a little hard time to figure this thing out

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. It's no problem that you're new to SoapUI, because OpenCSV doesn't have anything to do with SoapUI :)

## How to read a CSV file using OpenCSV and Groovy

```
@Grab('com.opencsv:opencsv:3.5')

import com.opencsv.CSVReader

/*
 * Mock some CSV data
 */
def reader = new StringReader(
'''column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
Hydrogen,1,H,1.00797,20.4
Carbon,6,C,12.0115,5100
Oxygen,8,O,15.9994,90.2
Gold,79,Gd,196.967,3239
Uranium,92,U,238.03,4091''')

/*
 * A nice mapping to give each field in the CSV file a name.
 * Much better than a bunch of propData[n] all over the place.
 */
def field = [
    ELEMENT: 0
]

reader.withReader {
    new CSVReader(it).eachWithIndex {list, index ->
        if(index == 0) {
            /*
             * Do whatever you need to do with the header of the CSV file.
             * Example:
             * testCase.setPropertyValue("data1",list[field.ELEMENT])         
             */         
        } else {
            /*
             * Do whatever you need to do with the remaining rows.
             * Example:
             * curTC.setPropertyValue("data1",list[field.ELEMENT])
             */
        }
    }
}
```

### Header and Data

You'll notice that in the `eachWithIndex()` loop there's an if-else. This makes it possible to process the header and then proceed with the remaining rows without having to restart reading the file.

You should be able to plug your SoapUI-specific code into the appropriate section.

### Varying number of fields

If for some reason your data rows don't all have the same number of fields, you can check how many fields there are like this: `list.size()`