# Groovy json parser

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to parse the following json into a csv file. I have a list of names and I am trying to get their potential ethnicities from this website: http://www.textmap.com/ethnicity/. I have worked with statistics processing language (SAS, Stata ... ) but I am not familiar with object-oriented languages. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have done:

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = jsonSlurper.parseText '''
{
    "George Washington": [
        { "scores":
            [ {"score": "0.07", "ethnicity": "Asian"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "GreaterAfrican"},
              {"score": "0.93", "ethnicity": "GreaterEuropean"}],
          "best":"GreaterEuropean" },
        { "scores":
            [ {"score": "1.00", "ethnicity": "British"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "Jewish"}, 
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "WestEuropean"}, 
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "EastEuropean"}],
          "best":"British" }
    ],
    "John Smith": [
        { "scores":
            [ {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "Asian"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "GreaterAfrican"},
              {"score": "1.00", "ethnicity": "GreaterEuropean"}],
          "best":"GreaterEuropean" },
        { "scores":
            [ {"score": "1.00", "ethnicity": "British"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "Jewish"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "WestEuropean"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "EastEuropean"}],
          "best": "British" }
    ],
    "Barack Obama": [
        { "scores":
            [ {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "Asian"},
              {"score": "1.00", "ethnicity": "GreaterAfrican"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "GreaterEuropean"}],
          "best":"GreaterAfrican"},
        {"scores":
            [ {"score": "1.00", "ethnicity": "Africans"},
              {"score": "0.00", "ethnicity": "Muslim"}],
          "best":"Africans"}
    ]
}    
'''

String[] header = new String[1];
      header[0] = result["George Washington"].best[1];


result.each {entry,value ->
println "Name: $entry Eth: $value.best" 
}
```

My questions are:
1. I don't know how to put the names (George Washington, etc) into a separate string component, say 1 element of the header.  Because of this, I am unable to export the data to a csv file.

2. I am not sure how to obtain specific components of an element within the object (please forgive my poor description). For example, the "best" element in the object could take two values. I am able to obtain the first one in the string definition, say best[1] but I don't know how to refer it in the loop command.
3. I also have a general question about the object-oriented language. It seems that an object could contain quite a few elements. How can I figure out how many elements there are in an object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object-oriented programming is a broad subject, but here's how you can generate the CSV data. Except for the *best*, because I don't know how to incorporate it.

```
def data = result.collect { name, map ->
    def output = [name: name]

    map.scores.flatten().each { output[it.ethnicity] = it.score }

    return output
}

def ethnicities = result.collect { name, map -> map.scores.ethnicity }.flatten().unique().toSorted()
def records = data.collect { person -> [person.name, ethnicities.collect { ethnicity -> person[ethnicity] ?: 0 }].flatten() }

def csv = records.inject(new StringBuilder("name,${ethnicities.join(',')}\n")) { builder, it -> 
    builder.append it.join(',') 
    builder.append "\n"

    return builder
}
```

`data` is a transformation of `result` and looks like this:

```
[
    ['name':'Barack Obama', 'Asian':'0.00', 'GreaterAfrican':'1.00', 'GreaterEuropean':'0.00', 'Africans':'1.00', 'Muslim':'0.00'], 
    ['name':'George Washington', 'Asian':'0.07', 'GreaterAfrican':'0.00', 'GreaterEuropean':'0.93', 'British':'1.00', 'Jewish':'0.00', 'WestEuropean':'0.00', 'EastEuropean':'0.00'], 
    ['name':'John Smith', 'Asian':'0.00', 'GreaterAfrican':'0.00', 'GreaterEuropean':'1.00', 'British':'1.00', 'Jewish':'0.00', 'WestEuropean':'0.00', 'EastEuropean':'0.00']
]
```

`ethnicities` is a unique list of all the ethnicities in the JSON data. `records` is a list containing the data to be *written* in the CSV format. It adds a zero value for any missing ethnicity scores. It looks like this:

```
[
    ['Barack Obama', '1.00', '0.00', 0, 0, '1.00', '0.00', 0, '0.00', 0],     
    ['George Washington', 0, '0.07', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.93', '0.00', 0, '0.00'], 
    ['John Smith', 0, '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', 0, '0.00']
]
```

Finally, the output looks like this:

```
name,Africans,Asian,British,EastEuropean,GreaterAfrican,GreaterEuropean,Jewish,Muslim,WestEuropean
Barack Obama,1.00,0.00,0,0,1.00,0.00,0,0.00,0
George Washington,0,0.07,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.93,0.00,0,0.00
John Smith,0,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0,0.00
```

## Hints

1. The `result` is a `Map` and the names are keys. So you can get a name like this: `def name = result.keySet()[0]`
2. The `result` object supports Groovy's [GPath](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#gpath_expressions).

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helps. I downloaded a opencsv jar file but I don't know how to invoke it in my program. Can you let me know where to install it on the Mac? Instead of asking many basic questions on stackoverflow, I guess I should really start learning Java or Groovy. I am mainly interested in text mining and obtaining data from web APIs. However, I don't have much background in programming( I use statistical packages more often). Do you have a recommendation where I can get started? Thanks!

Comment: See this on how to use jars in a Groovy script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463403/im-trying-read-3-or-more-column-from-csv-file-it-giving-me-an-index-error-any/32402668#32402668. The Groovy documentation is pretty good. For in-dept knowledge you can read Groovy in Action Second Edition.